Postfix is not running after reboot
After I reboot my system, the SMTP-Server stops working and ports 25 and 465 are not reachable. When trying to send an email from Roundcube, I get the following error message: SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed.
I run postfix status and this is the output:
postfix: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
postfix: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
postfix: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running

But if I restart Postfix it starts running again. Why is that? Is there a way to restart Postfix automatically on every reboot?

Can you post the service definition file? I assume that it should probably have a Requires or Wants set that delays startup until after other units are up... though I don't know which offhand.

Check for the obvious first - Make sure the service is enabled:
sudo systemctl is-enabled postfix

If it’s not enabled, then it won’t start on reboot. To enable it:
sudo systemctl enable --now postfix

After that, reboot and check again.

I checked and the output says its enabled.

Is there a way to restart Postfix automatically on every reboot?

Keep in mind that Ask Ubuntu is "a little bit different from other sites." The way your post was phrased, it asked questions, which really shouldn't be done in an answer.  However, your post really is an attempt at an answer, so I've edited it to reword the "questions" into "suggestions".

@DavidM The act of enabling a service already fulfills your "Restart postfix on every reboot".  As to why it's not running on reboot, probably means that something else is at play here.  Take a look at: systemctl status postfix, and journalctl -u postfix and see if there are any obvious errors.  If need be, post any suspect lines here.  I am new here, so I may not be commenting correctly, or perhaps even using the wrong method in replying!  Please feel free to edit my comment if need be.

@DavidM I just found this post: link, which suggests that it might be due to port 25 already being in use.  Do you see postfix/master[17067]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use in your postfix status command?
